# 403 error from Google Drive direct link due to multiple accounts logged in

Tags: google-drive-api

I have a number of images in Google Drive and I am wanting to use them in various ways via the direct link style:

https://drive.google.com/uc?id=DOCID

In Chrome I am logged into three different Google accounts, my corporate one, my personal one, and one other. If I navigate through the Google Drive interface to my files in the corporate account I can see them fine. If I use the form https://drive.google.com/open?id=DOCID then the Google Drive interface opens properly with the image displayed. However, when I try to access the file directly using the uc?id= URL style above I get a 403 error.

*"403. That’s an error.
We're sorry, but you do not have access to this page. That’s all we know."*

I have tracked this down to being because when I use this URL form, for some reason Chrome or Google Drive are using the wrong authentication credentials - i.e. the ones from my personal account even though this file is in my corporate account.

I've proved this by firing up Firefox, which isn't authenticated to any account, logging in as my corporate user, and then using the URL above: bingo, the image is displayed.

So my question: is there any way to force the URL style above to use the correct set of credentials when accessing the file?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `drive.google.com/u/1/uc?id=DOCID` or `drive.google.com/a/mycorporatedomain.com/uc?id=DOCID`

However, do not rely on these URL's not changing in the future.

Answer (score 0):

Log out of all the accounts and only log in just one needed account. This works for me. The google free 15 GB is good since I can always create new email but difficulty in downloading file give drop box an edge.