# 403 errors for Gdrive API V3 when switching between multiple accounts

Tags: node.js, google-api, google-drive-api, google-api-nodejs-client

I'm looking for a solution to help users bypass a 403 forbidden when they switch accounts and click a `webViewLink` or `webContentLink` to download a file.

We're using Gdrive API V3(node) with a google service account. We're aggregating files to be easily accessed by our team. The server populates the content and then users access them via a link.

So the issue is this:

- User logs in
- They do their thing, download some content, no issues because they are logged into their work account
- User goes to check their personal email, or grab something from Drive, so they switch google accounts
- User then tries to access content again(we're using `webContentLink/webViewLink`) and they get a 403

This is totally understandable, Google doesn't know that it's the same person trying to access the content.

A few high level solutions I thought of:

1. When link is clicked, add a permission to allow anyone to view it, and set it to expire within n seconds(might not be possible with permissions.create)
2. Somehow save the correct auth and use that for when you click a link(realizing that I'm not sure how the browser knows which token to send)
3. Turn on "Anyone with link can view"(this is problematic for security reasons, in case someone left the company and still had the link or someone stumbled upon it)
4. Add auth to the client with the service account credentials
5. Export and download these files on the server directly(possible with .key and other weird formats?)

A lot of the files needing to be accessed are `.key` and `.mov` among others such as `.ppt` and drive files/folders.

So two(ish) questions here:

1. What's the best way to address this issue? Is it possible to use the nodejs-client library to download all of these filetypes programmatically? Is this something that delegating domain-wide authority might solve?
2. Is it possible to specify which credentials are used client side, even though the server is doing all of the initial auth?

Thanks for any help and insight here! This is a total pain!

Comment: I don't completely understand your use case, however, this tidbit might help. It's possible to include an Access Token as part of the URL (?access_token=xxxxx)

Comment: Think of a simple UI for viewing your drive files so that a team can  easily access them without needing to actually visit drive and poke around. I looked at the auth object that comes back and I see some links to a token, but none of them actually gave me one. Where does that token reside if I'm using a service account? Thanks @pinoyyid!

Comment: @pinoyyid I now realize that you were the person who answered a similar question(see answer) and want to know where you found this option to force the auth with '/a/corpdomain'. Is this documented somewhere? Is the fact that this could change documented somewhere as well?

Comment: afaik it's not documented. I discovered it by observing the URLs generated if I went to say GDrive by clicking the GDrive icon in Gmail

Comment: @pinoyyid Thanks so much for your response! You're a lifesaver! Last question: Since I'm using a service account, I don't get an access_token, is there any other way to specify in the request that the service account should get full access(aka no 403)?

Comment: you always have an access token, regardless of what account type you are using.

Comment: @pinoyyid Oh interesting. I looked at the auth object I get back from gdrive api and I didn't get anything back under credentials that said access_token.

Comment: take a step back and make sure you understand that OAuth and the Drive API are two different things, connected by an Access Token. OAuth (2 legged Service Account or 3 legged User Account) will produce an Access Token. OAuth doesn't care what you do with that token. GDrive needs an Access Token (unless the files are public). GDrive doesn't care how you got that token.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Here's the quick fix solution:**

[403 error from Google Drive direct link due to multiple accounts logged in](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41616072/403-error-from-google-drive-direct-link-due-to-multiple-accounts-logged-in)

> You can use drive.google.com/u/1/uc?id=DOCID or
>   drive.google.com/a/mycorporatedomain.com/uc?id=DOCID
>
> However, do not rely on these URL's not changing in the future.

**Here's a more robust solution if you're using a server side API:**

The idea is to hijack the link being clicked, get the metadata you need(ID, filename, mimeType) and request the file from google via the Node server. You can specify the response as a stream, and send that stream to be opened via an inline attachment.

These two links will help:

[node/express Force browser to download file with custom name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36936605/node-express-force-browser-to-download-file-with-custom-name)

[How to send a file from remote URL as a GET response in Node.js Express app?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26288055/how-to-send-a-file-from-remote-url-as-a-get-response-in-node-js-express-app)

In the context of an Express App, here's what it might look like:

```
// I'm using an async function here, but it may not be best practice.
app.get('/download', async function(req, res, next) {
  // get the metadata from req.query
  const fileId = req.query.id;
  const filename = req.query.name;
  const mimeType = req.query.mimeType;
  const inlineFilename = `inline;filename=${ filename }`;

  // Set the Content-Disposition to specify a filename
  // Set the Content-Type to accept a stream, because that's what we want back from google.
  res.set("Content-Disposition", inlineFilename);
  res.set("Content-Type", "application/octet-stream");

  // This returns a data stream from google so that we are able to pipe the result.
  const fileStream = await downloadFile(fileId);

  // Pipe the stream to the res. This sends the file stream to the client to be downloaded
  fileStream.pipe(res);

});
```

downloadFile can look something like this(using [google-api-nodejs-client](https://github.com/google/google-api-nodejs-client/blob/master/samples/drive/download.js)):

```
downloadFile: async function(fileId) {
  try {      
    const response = await drive.files.get(
      {fileId, alt: 'media'},
      {responseType: 'stream'}
    );

    return response.data
  } catch (error) {
    console.error(error);
 }
```

}

Comment: Does this have any caveats? Security, memory usage? Anything else I should keep in mind? Thanks!